# Open a jQuery Mobile Collapsible Set

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

In jQuery Mobile, I have a collapsible set:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" class="ui-collapsible-set ui-group-theme-inherit ui-corner-all">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed ui-first-child">
        <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed"><a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">Tab 1</a></h3>
        <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
            <p>Content 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed ui-first-child">
        <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed"><a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">Tab 2</a></h3>
        <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
            <p>Content 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed ui-first-child">
        <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed"><a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">Tab 3</a></h3>
        <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
            <p>Content 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I open, for example, the second panel programmatically?

Comment: your `collapsibleset` markup seems unlikely, did you checked the docs here: [Collapsible set](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/collapsibleset/) ? It seems to me you mixed pre-enhanced markup with data-role enhancement requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `collapse()` method.

```
$('PUT_HERE_A_SELECTOR_FOR_YOUR_SECOND_PANEL').collapsible('collapse');
```

And that's it.

Cya

Comment: Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on collapsible prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'collapse'

Comment: Are you putting it after the jQuery Mobile `pageinit` event?

Comment: Yeah, I'm putting it in $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {});

Comment: Try to capture the view itself, something like this:

`$('#YourPageName').bind( 'pageinit',function(event){
   // The collapse method here;
});`

Comment: If this do not work, can you post a fiddle with an example your code?